# Install4j 8.0 release timeline and features

Tags: install4j

I am looking for install4j 8 release time line and its features.

Does intall4j 8 supports 
1. Apple OS Notarization?
2. Is it compatible with Java 11. In other words what is the least install4j 
   version that supports Java 11
3. Also any plans to support Open JDK

Comment: Stackoverflow really is not a suitable medium for this kind of question, please contact support@ej-technologies.com. But yes, notarization is planned, Java 11 and OpenJDK are already supported by install4j 7.

Comment: Thanks Ingo. will follow as you suggested